# get an error while exporting access database to sharepoint 2007 lists: lookup contains values that do not exist in the related table

Tags: lookup-column, access

I try to export a table in a access database to sharepoint 2007. All related tables are automatic exported to SharePoint as lists. SharePoint creates lookup fields for each relation. Under the export I got the following error:

> there was an error mapping lookup columns. lookup contains values that
>   do not exist in the related table

[image]

After this error, the export will do a rollback and removes all the exported tables in sharepoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was, there were some blank values at a foreign key column. I set some default value. Now it works fine.